# Подскажите, как сделать вывод тем для постов?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Я делаю проект "Форум", что-то похожее на reddit. При нажатии на пункт выпадающего списка Topic должны выводиться посты, соответствующие нажатой теме. У меня ничего не выводится. Как исправить?

Index.cshtml

```
@using Forum_MVC.Data.Entities;
@model MyViewModel;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
@using System.Linq;
<body>
    <div class="d-flex-container">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-pink dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="categoryDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        @if (Model.SelectedCategoryId == 0)
                        {
                            <span>All Categories</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Model.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.SelectedCategoryId)?.Name
                        }
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="categoryDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Index", new { selectedCategoryId = 0, topicId = Model.SelectedTopicId })">All Categories</a></li>
                        @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
                        {
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Index", new { selectedCategoryId = category.Id, topicId = Model.SelectedTopicId })">@category.Name</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }

            <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetSelectedTopic">
                <div class="dropdown mt-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-pink dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="topicDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        @if (Model.SelectedTopicId == 0)
                        {
                            <span>All Topics</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Model.TopicOfPosts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.SelectedTopicId)?.Name
                        }
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="topicDropdown">
                        @foreach (var topic in Model.TopicOfPosts)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <button type="submit" name="selectedTopicId" value="@topic.Id" class="dropdown-item">@topic.Name</button>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="selectedCategoryId" value="@Model.SelectedCategoryId" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selectedTopicId" value="@Model.SelectedTopicId" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            @if (Model != null && Model.Posts.Any())
            {
                foreach (var i in Model.Posts)
                {
                    <div class="card pink-card text-white mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header">@i.Title</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">@i.Text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }

            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    @for (var i = 1; i <= Math.Ceiling((double)Model.TotalPosts / Model.PageSize); i++)
                    {
                        <li class="page-item @(i == Model.PageNumber ? "active" : "")">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/Home/Index?pageNumber=@i&pageSize=@Model.PageSize">@i</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
using Forum_MVC.Data.Entities;

namespace Forum_MVC.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<TopicOfPost> TopicOfPosts { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int TotalPosts { get; set; }
        public TopicOfPost SelectedTopic { get; set; }
        public int SelectedTopicId { get; set; } 
        public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using Forum_MVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Forum_MVC.Data;
using Forum_MVC.Data.Entities;

namespace Forum_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        ForumDbContext context = new ForumDbContext();

        public HomeController()
        {
        }

        public IActionResult Index(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 3, int selectedCategoryId = 0, int selectedTopicId = 0)
        {
            var totalPosts = context.Posts.Count();

            var filteredPosts = context.Posts.AsQueryable();

            if (selectedCategoryId != 0)
            {
                filteredPosts = filteredPosts.Where(p => p.CategoryId == selectedCategoryId);
            }

            if (selectedTopicId != 0)
            {
                filteredPosts = filteredPosts.Where(p => p.TopicOfPostId == selectedTopicId);
            }

            var posts = filteredPosts
                .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();

            var categories = context.Categories.ToList();
            var topicOfPosts = context.TopicsOfPosts.ToList();

            MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
            {
                Posts = posts,
                Categories = categories,
                TopicOfPosts = topicOfPosts,
                PageNumber = pageNumber,
                PageSize = pageSize,
                TotalPosts = totalPosts,
                SelectedCategoryId = selectedCategoryId,
                SelectedTopicId = selectedTopicId,
                SelectedTopic = context.TopicsOfPosts.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == selectedTopicId)
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SetSelectedTopic(int selectedTopicId, int selectedCategoryId)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { selectedCategoryId = selectedCategoryId, selectedTopicId = selectedTopicId });
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В режиме отладки смотрите, что приходит в `SetSelectedTopic` и далее в `Index`. Или логирование сделайте.